Jetpack compose vs xml for app development
I'm a beginner for android app development, as I'm a java developer and know basics of kotlin there are choices like jetpack compose and xml  for ui design. I need a suggestion from developers to grow my knowledge. which is the valuable and comfortable to developer.
I'm open my mind to get any suggestion so I'm very thankful in advance

I guess you need to share some more information to get useful feedback.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

"tried to connect with android studio" - what does this mean? Connect how? "I faced only failures because of" - what failures? Because of what? Help us help you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Develop UI for Android
Jetpack Compose is Android's recommended modern toolkit for building native UI.
Why adopt Compose
Compare Compose and View metrics
Migrate existing View-based apps

Having worked in both xml and compose based systems i can confirm jetpack compose being FAR better.

Are you looking to land a role in Native Android development? Are you working looking to work on newer technologies in Kotlin? What is your goal?
If you are going to work in a native role involving native Android, then you'll need a knowledge of xml based UI as there most likely is old code that has been developed in it. There is great documentation by Google for it:
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout
Modern development primarily occurs in Compose, declarative UI just has many more advantages and allows for clearer and cleaner code.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/documentation
If you are brand new, check out the CodeLabs offered on the website too:
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics#0
